# How to create a XIB that works from iPhone 4 to iPhone 6 Plus without using size classes and storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, autolayout, xcode5.1.1

I have to design an application that supports iOS versions from 6.1 to 8.1. In order to support iOS 6.1, i can't create storyboards with size classes. So i have to use only XIBs and use auto layout for the XIBs.

When i run my application in Xcode 6.1, it looks like all the layouts are perfectly fine. But when i run the same application in Xcode 5.1.1, all the views are reshuffled starting from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5.

Now i have to design my XIBs in such a way that the views are layed out properly in all the devices from iPhone 4 to iPhone 6 Plus. Can someone please suggest me a proper way of how i can create the XIBs that supports all the devices?

Comment: if your min support version is iOS 6 you can use autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has really some [solid documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) on how to use autolayout and build dynamically sizing screens using constraints. Another solid tutorial to check out is [this](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) one from appcoda. Can be a little confusing at first but once you understand constraints making screens that look nice for all screen sizes is actually pretty straightforward

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit? Please don't just cite the documentation but reference it relevant to OPs question.

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa yes they will